# Can Maxwell's electromagnetic vector field be simplified to a scalar field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wavefunction, field-theory, maxwell-equations

Maxwell's electromagnetism essentially associates **6** numbers $[E_x, E_y, E_z, B_x, B_y, B_z]$ to every point in space.

The time evolution of all six numbers is completely deterministic, but follows very convoluted rules, along the lines of:

$$E_xchange = B_z[x,y+1,z] - B_z[x,y,z] - B_y[x,y,z+1] + B_y[x,y,z]$$
$$E_ychange = B_z[x+1,y,z] - B_z[x,y,z] - B_x[x,y,z+1] + B_x[x,y,z]$$
$$E_zchange = B_y[x+1,y,z] - B_y[x,y,z] - B_x[x,y+1,z] + B_x[x,y,z]$$
$$B_xchange = E_z[x,y,z] - E_z[x,y+1,z] - E_y[x,y,z] + E_y[x,y,z+1]$$
$$B_ychange = E_z[x,y,z] - E_z[x+1,y,z] - E_x[x,y,z] + E_x[x,y,z+1]$$
$$B_zchange = E_y[x,y,z] - E_y[x+1,y,z] - E_x[x,y,z] + E_x[x,y+1,z]$$

In contrast, the quantum mechanic's wavefunction $\psi$ follows a much cleaner time evolution rule, having assigned only **2** numbers [Re, Im] to every point in space. There is no definable curl operation because the field is scalar rather than vector.

*Is it provable in theory that Maxwell's **6** numbers are the minimum possible to represent electromagnetic behavior, or is it possible to achieve the same with only **2** numbers (following different rules) in the spirit of quantum mechanic's wavefunction?*

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it provable in theory that Maxwell's $6$ numbers are the minimum possible
> to represent electromagnetic behavior ...?*

Maxwell's $6$ electromagnetic field components ($E_x,E_y,E_z,B_x,B_y,B_z$)
are not the minimum possible number. You can bring it down to an
[electromagnetic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential) with $4$ components (usually called $\Phi,A_x,A_y,A_z$).
The electromagnetic fields can be derived from these potentials:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}&=-\nabla\Phi-\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t} \\
\mathbf{B}&=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}
\end{align}$$

Then one half of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention)
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{B}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}+\nabla\times\mathbf{E}&=\mathbf{0}
\end{align}$$
is automatically satisfied.
And the other half of Maxwell's equations leads to [evolution rules
for the potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Alternative_formulations) (which are now 2nd order differential equations):
$$\begin{align}
-\nabla^2\Phi-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A})
&=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \\
  \left(-\nabla^2+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\mathbf{A}
 +\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}+\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}\right)
&=\mu_0\mathbf{J}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you. i have tried to derive the explicit time evolution rules $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}$ from the last 2 equations, but run into the following problem: The last equation is a simultaneous equation having both $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \vec A}{\partial t^2}$ . The first equation has  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial z})$ which to my knowledge cannot recover $\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's a well known theorem that in scalar or tensor fields like charges attract, whereas in vector fields like charges repel. Since like electric charges repel, electromagnetism must be a vector field.

Quantum mechanically, scalar fields are mediated by spin 0 particles, vector fields by spin 1 particles, and tensor fields by spin 2 particles. The photon (quantum of the electromagnetic field) is a spin 1 particle.

Comment: thank you. which theorem mathematically connects like charge attraction or repulsion to scalar or vector field components interaction?

Comment: That's a very good question! it seems to be one of those things that "everybody knows", in that I've seen it in many places, but when I looked for the formal definition I couldn't find it. Misner Thorne and Wheeler's Gravitation shows in Exercise 7.2 that a vector theory of gravity is infeasible. https://towardsdatascience.com/gravity-and-electric-charges-attraction-and-repulsion-b2b5f8f91caa has a nice discussion of attraction and repulsion in quantum mechanics and that like charges repel in a vector theory...

Comment: ... and I suspect that any good QFT textbook will discuss the relationship between spin and attraction/repulsion (there are links in the article I mentioned above). To step back a bit, Maxwell's equations are very thoroughly well known, and if they could significantly be simplified in any way it likely would have happened by now (and indeed has happened: modern 4D formulations are much simpler than the complicated equations Maxwell originally introduced).

Comment: Thank you vm. The link is great at explaining this.  I'm afraid i might have to learn what i can without full textbook exposition, as i do not have years to spend learning it, as it really ideally should be learned :(